# Admob banner change frame for different screen dimensions

Tags: objective-c, admob

I'm trying to get my Admob ad to adjust between all the different iPhone screen sizes that Apple offers, but I can't figure out how to get it to adjust automatically or by using different code.

In my `viewdidload`

```
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 430, 320, 50)];
bannerView_.adUnitID = @"";
bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:bannerView_];
[bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", nil ];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `adSize` property to Google's set banner size `kGADAdSizeBanner`. Then you set your `GADBannerView`'s `frame` relative to the `view`. The following code places the `GADBannerView` on the bottom of your `view`.

```
admobBannerView.adSize = kGADAdSizeBanner;
admobBannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - admobBannerView.frame.size.height , self.view.frame.size.width, admobBannerView.frame.size.height);
```

- `x` - Set to origin of `0`
- `y` - Set origin to the `view`'s height. But this will make it appear off the bottom of the screen. So, we must subtract the height of our `GADBannerView` to move it up onto the screen: `self.view.frame.size.height - admobBannerView.frame.size.height`
- `width` - Set it to the width of the `view`: `self.view.frame.size.width`
- `height` - Set it to the height of our `GADBannerView`: `admobBannerView.frame.size.height`

[**Banner Ad Customization**](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/banner)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating the banner programmatically instead of with Storyboard, I would check to find out what the height of the screen is.  I use the following code to determine what phone someone is on.

```
CGFloat greaterPixelDimension = (CGFloat) fmaxf(((float)[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height), ((float)[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width));
```

I would then create the bannerview in the code like this:

```
if (greaterPixelDimension == 736) {  //6 plus
    bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, ###, 4--, 50)];
}
else if (greaterPixelDimension == 667){  // 6
     bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, ###, 3--, 50)];
}
else if(greaterPixelDimension == 568){  // 5
     bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 430, 320, 50)];
}
```

etc.  (obviously replace the ### and 3-- with the respective points, I forget the numbers off the top of my head)

Comment: This is the old way of doing things and worked fine when you only had two screen dimensions to worry about. But, with all the different devices available now, and the many more to come, this list will only grow and need to be updated continually.

Comment: Good point Daniel, seems stupid that I would dynamically get the height of the screen and then hardcode the widths.  That is what happens when you take code that is looking to differentiate for image resolutions and modify it.  Thanks for pointing that out!